# How can I use sqlalchemy to produce a list of values without creating objects?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have this code:

```
things = Thing.query.filter_by(user_id=user_id).all()
```

Afterward I then iterate over `things` and only use `thing.id`, so I can be more effecient by only requesting the `id` of each row:

```
things = Thing.query.with_entities(Thing.id).filter_by(user_id=user_id).all()
```

To be even more efficient, I'd like to not create the `Thing` objects in memory in the first place. In rails this would be done with [`pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck). Is there something equivalent with sqlalchemy?

Comment: `with_entities` is the equivalent of `pluck`. It emits `SELECT id FROM thing WHERE user_id = ...`, not `SELECT * FROM thing WHERE user_id = ...`.

Comment: And then a list of lists is returned? Or a list of `Thing`s?

Comment: It gives you a list of integers.

Comment: looks like it's a list of "sqlalchemy.util._collections.result" `type(Thing.query.with_entities(Thing.id).all()[0])` => `<class 'sqlalchemy.util._collections.result'>`

Comment: Oops, you're totally right. It's effectively a list of tuples.

Comment: So, that's much better than generating a list of Thing objects (hopefully sqlalchemy doesnt' do that as an intermediary?…) — but i'd still like to not have to map it down to a list if integers afterward if possible.. but maybe sqlalchemy doesn't support that.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Not to my knowledge. It's slightly annoying, but it's not going to have a hefty performance penalty.